# Switching from Win32 to Windows Mobile 6: any tips?

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile

I'm starting on a Windows Mobile project (no .NET Compact Framework - just native code). Having been a Win32 programmer (managed and native) for many years, I probably have some "desktop-isms" built in my brain that just don't translate well to the mobile world.

Are there any tips you may want to share about typical pitfalls for someone who's just starting on WinMo development coming from the desktop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My biggest tips would be

- Use resources sparingly (memory, threads)
- Measure the performance of everything on actual hardware, not the emulator.

These are generally good things to do on all mobile/embedded hardware.

Answer (score 1):

TTC - Trust the Compiler (if it's the one in VS2005 or VS2008). Just beacuse it's a scaled down system doesn't mean it's a scaled down compiler. It knows what it does, I assure you. So don't try to play dirty tricks for "optimization" - it **is** a good compiler.